# document.getElementById(...) returns undefined in Firefox

Tags: javascript

i have an issue with a javascript function :

JS code :

```
function ouvrirPopupAvecImprEcran(){
    var name= document.getElementById("myForm:currentName").value;
    var code= document.getElementById("myForm:currentCode").value;
...
}
```

This function works with Chrome, but when i try with firefox, the function getElementById returns "undefined". I have looked at my generated HTML output to see if the id already exist but they don't.

Generated HTML output :

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="/MyProject/p/handleTest.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <select id="myForm:currentName" size="1" name="myForm:currentName"> 
    ...
    </select>
    ...
    <input name="myForm:j_idt556" value="Print" onclick="return ouvrirPopupAvecImprEcran();" type="submit">
    ...
    <input id="myForm:currentCode" name="myForm:currentCode" value="Hey" type="hidden">
</form>
```

I don't understand why this code doesn't work in Firefox.

Could you help me, please?

Thank you.

Comment: [Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/jF9eX/) does not show the problem you describe in Firefox 24.0 or 25.0.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 24.0

Comment: Code provided works fine in FIrefox. Something else is wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/n7mfw/

Comment: When does `ouvrirPopupAvecImprEcran` get called?

Comment: I have edited my first post.

Comment: Your code still doesn't show the problem. You need to create a reduced test case that actually has the problem in it.

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns `null` if the element is not found, not `undefined` - something else is wrong with your code.

Answer (score -1):

It could be that Firefox has troubles with the colon in the ID string. could you try escaping the colon by putting `\\` before it?

Comment: I don't use colon in my id name, it's autogenerated. In my xhtml code, i have <h:selectOneMenu id="currentName" ... /> for example.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Whether the code is autogenerated or custom made, Javascript does not care about that. A colon is a special character for CSS and JS and as such needs to be escaped when used in a string or a selector.

Comment: @nzall For `getElementById` the colon is not a problem, at least it should not be one. For the `querySelector` it needs to be escaped because pseudo classes have a `:` at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

change the ":" for "_"

in html

in javascript

var name= document.getElementById("myForm_currentName").value;

try this